# Angularfire .5 can't bind to data after login authentication

Tags: firebase, angularfire

So here is the next step ( which has failed ) in trying to use v0.5.  Once you have logged in succesfully with a JWT, any attempt to bind will result in an undefined value.  Binding to a public database works in my experiments but not with a private database where the user has logged in AND has the proper permissions to write to that datastore ( Keep in mind, this is a port of a working app from .4 ).   Here is the code that will not bind ( $rootScope.profile == undefined ):

```
myApp.app.run(['$rootScope','$firebase','$firebaseAuth',
  function($rootScope, $firebase,$firebaseAuth ) {
      var ref = new Firebase("mydatabase.firebaseio.com");
      $rootScope.fbAuth = $firebaseAuth(ref);
      console.log($rootScope.fbAuth.user);

  var    jwt="eyJhbGciOiAiSFMyN.... // A VALID JAVA WEB TOKEN...trust me.

  $rootScope.fbAuth.$login(jwt);
  $rootScope.$on("$firebaseAuth:login", function(e, user) {
          $rootScope.user = user;
          var refUsers = new Firebase('mydatabase.firebaseio.com'+'/users/'+user.id);
          $rootScope.fbUser = $firebase(refUsers);
          $rootScope.fbUser.$on("loaded", function() {
              $rootScope.fbUser.$bind($rootScope, "profile").then (function(unbind){
                  alert(unbind);
                  console.log($rootScope.profile);
              });
          });
  });
}]);
```

Clarification:
The documentation shows the example:

```
$scope.items.$bind($scope, "remoteItems");
$scope.remoteItems.bar = "foo";  // new Firebase(URL + "/bar") is now "foo".
alert($scope.remoteItems);
```

> > This will show undefined
> >        if you have intiated $scope.remoteItems={};
> >        then this will update firebase and erase the data bound to $scope.items ( undesirable IMHO)

```
  // If you were to try:
  $scope.items.$bind($scope,'remoteItems')  // Fails with undefined and no binding.

 // If you were to try:
 $scope.remoteItems = {};  // or similar init
 $scope.items.$bind($scope,'remoteItems')  // wipes out data stored at refItems on firebase.
```

I have not found a way to get the bind to work on my database and it is definitely not a security issue.

Comment: With further experimentation I have found that if I create the remote object on the scope before it will end up bound AND will write the contents of the  remote object to firebase.  This is undesirable.  However this lead me to pass the same name as the object that has the $bind method.  This has the desired result but is still not consistent with the docs.

Comment: Can you clarify the point about having to use the same name as the object that has the $bind method? How can we make the docs clearer in that regard?

Comment: Anant -- see edits in original question.

Comment: And I actually misspoke.  I can not get three way binding to work even if it is named the same.

Comment: Ok.  I read the angularfire code.  The issue is that you expect the model to exist.  So to create three way binding in the same way it was implemented in v0.4 you need to do the following using your doc example:

   $scope.remoteItems = angular.copy($scope.items);
   $scope.items.$bind($scope, 'remoteItems');

If you do this you basically get the same type of bound behavior found in v0.4.  However now you have to create two explicit copies of the data on the scope.  This is not exactly how I would implement it. Let me know if you think I have misunderstood anything.

Comment: I am also getting many FIREBASE console.log messages.  The most alarming is the it says: Attempt to write null to /users/...

Comment: This problem was properly fixed in Angularfire 0.7.2-pre that you can find on github.